# C/C++ : exporting variable from a .h

Tags: c++

In C/C++, I would like to use from main.cpp a ready-to-use variable (mTab) that is :

1. declared and initialized in lib.h
2. implemented in lib.cpp

I can't make this work : what's wrong ? Seems typedef is ignored and I don't get why ?

Note :

1. as mTab must be the same for each user of lib.h, I added the static keyword
2. as static variable must always be initialized (to avoid unexpected behavior), I initialized mTab in lib.h
3. when I move the mTab initialisation in lib.cpp : compilation is KO
4. when I move the mTab declaration and initialisation in lib.cpp, and, use "extern" in main.cpp : compilation is KO
5. the only way to get compilation OK is to put mTab declaration and initialisation inside the main scope in main.cpp... Which is not what I want ! (inside main scope compilation is OK. outside main scope, that is at include level, compilation is KO)

Thanks for help,

FH

```
~>more *
```

lib.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"

void m1 ( unsigned int const iDataSize, int * const iopData ) { return; }
void m2 ( unsigned int const iDataSize, int * const iopData ) { return; }
```

lib.h

```
#ifndef __lib__
#define __lib__
void m1 ( unsigned int const iDataSize, int * const iopData );
void m2 ( unsigned int const iDataSize, int * const iopData );
typedef void ( *pF ) ( unsigned int const iDataSize, int * const iopData );
static pF mTab[2]; // Ready-to-use variable to be exported
mTab[0] = &m1;
mTab[1] = &m2;
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include "lib.h"
#include <stddef.h> // NULL

int main ()
{
  (*mTab[0]) ( 0, NULL );
  (*mTab[1]) ( 0, NULL );

  return 0;
}
```

Makefile

```
all:
    gcc -I. -c lib.cpp -o lib.o
    gcc -I. -c main.cpp -o main.o
    gcc -I. lib.o main.o -o main.exe
```

Console:

```
~>make
gcc -I. -c lib.cpp -o lib.o
In file included from lib.cpp:1:0:
lib.h:7:1: error: ‘mTab’ does not name a type
lib.h:8:1: error: ‘mTab’ does not name a type
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

Comment: You are receiving down votes because Stack Overflow is not a place for tutoring; you should use other sources for normal learning. Stack Overflow is better used for questions and problems that puzzle people who have already largely learned a subject.

Answer (score 9):

First, only put declarations, not definitions of objects or functions, in shared header files. For mTab, use this in lib.h:

```
extern pF mTab[2];
```

Second, define an object in one and only one source file. Put this in lib.cpp:

```
pf mTab[2] = { m1, m2 };
```

Third, `mTab[0] = &m1;` is not an initialization of mTab. It would be an assignment statement, but it is in the wrong place, because you cannot have assignment statements at file scope. The proper way to initialize mTab is shown above. (Assignments are different from initializations. Assignments are executable statements and must be inside function bodies. An initialization is part of the creation of an object, which may happen prior to primary execution of the program.)

Fourth, `static` does not make an object be the same for each user. It has two effects, which may vary depending on where it is used. When used at file scope, it says that the identifier has internal linkage, which means the identifier refers **only** to an object in the current compilation; it is **not** linked externally to the same identifier in other compilations. So it actually means the opposite of what you wrote; it means each source file has its own `mTab`, not that they share one `mTab`. (The second effect of static `static` is to give an object static storage duration, so its lifetime is the entire execution of the program. However, this has no effect at file scope because an object declared at file scope has static storage duration by default.)

Comment: In the declaration, you can even leave out the array size, leaving it at `extern pF mTab[]`. Of course it would be useful to tell the user of this array the maximum size, so that you don't go out of bounds.

Answer (score 1):

```
mTab[0] = &m1;
```

You can't do that in global namespace. Try defining it in one of the cpps and have it as 'extern' in the header;

Answer (score 0):

`static` means something else in this context. `static` indicates the variable has internal linkage. This means that a separate variable will exist for each compilation unit. You want to use `extern` in your header.

Also, please choose a different symbol besides `__lib__` for your include guard. Identifiers containing a double underscore are reserved for the implementation’s use.

Lastly, as ahoka indicated, you cannot place that code at namespace scope. That would only be valid in a function. So do it this way:

lib.h

```
extern pF mTab[2];
```

lib.cpp

```
pF mTab[2] = {&m1, &m2};
```